# Removing the filename extension from a string

Tags: php, breadcrumbs

I'm creating a breadcrumb script like this:

```
<?php 

    if($location = substr(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), 1)) 
         $dirlist = explode('/', $location); 
    else 
         $dirlist = array();

       $count = array_push($dirlist, basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])); 
       $address = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; 
         echo '<a href="'.$address.'">home</a>';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) 
         echo ' » <a href="'.($address .='/'.$dirlist[$i]).'">'.$dirlist[$i].'</a>';

?>
```

If form url is *http:// domain /school/students.php*,
the result is like this: `( home » school » students.php )`

Question: How to eliminate the extension *.php* file *students.php*,
be like this `( home » school » students )` ??

Comment: wondering why's this question downvoted 3 times, it shows effort and it's clear

Answer (score 1):

No matter how long is the extension or its name, this will work :

```
<?php
if($location = substr(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), 1)) 
    $dirlist = explode('/', $location); 
else 
     $dirlist = array();

   $count = array_push($dirlist, basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])); 
   $address = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; 
     echo '<a href="'.$address.'">home</a>';

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $result = $dirlist[$i];
    if ($i == ($count-1)) { // if last element
        $lastDot = strripos($result,'.') ;
        $result = substr($result,0,$lastDot) ;          
    }       
    echo ' » <a href="'.($address .='/'.$dirlist[$i]).'">'.$result.'</a>';
}
```

?>

Comment: You welcome ! Click the little arrow above the 0 if you think it is useful for you. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

how about using string replacement?

Here's a bit of code that may point you in the right direction, replacing your for loop.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

    $label = str_replace('.php', '', $dirlist[$i]);
    echo ' » <a href="'.($address .='/'.$dirlist[$i]).'">'.$label.'</a>';

}
```

Comment: get notice: Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C: ... on line 14

Answer (score 0):

Try deducting string

```
<?php 

if($location = substr(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), 1)) 
     $dirlist = explode('/', $location); 
else 
     $dirlist = array();

   $count = array_push($dirlist, basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])); 
   $address = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; 
     echo '<a href="'.$address.'">home</a>';
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) 
if(!isset($dirlist[$i+1]))
{
     echo ' » <a href="'.($address .='/'.$dirlist[$i]).'">'.substr($dirlist[$i],0,-4).'</a>';
}
else
{
 echo ' » <a href="'.($address .='/'.$dirlist[$i]).'">'.$dirlist[$i].'</a>';
}

?>
```

this will work.

Comment: the result is the same as above, Notice: Undefined offset 2 in C: .. How do I use isset??

Comment: See the answer. I think This is what you want.